# Subversion does not remember my user/password

Tags: svn

I've installed Subversion on Ubuntu following the guide *[Installation of Subversion on Ubuntu, with Apache, SSL, and BasicAuth.](http://alephzarro.com/blog/2007/01/07/installation-of-subversion-on-ubuntu-with-apache-ssl-and-basicauth)*.

It works, and I was able commit and create different repositories, but somehow, from time to time (sometimes minutes), when trying to do a commit, I'm forced to reset or recreate my user and password with the following command.

```
htpasswd2 -c -m /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd $AUTH_USER
```

Because SVN does not recognize my user/password anymore.

I'm using TortoiseSVN as SVN Client. I would like to know why this is happening. Maybe it's a configuration issue, or maybe TortoiseSVN is sending invalid credentials, causing a locked account. Since I'm far from being an SVN expert/administrator. Are there some pointers in order to attack the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your password-file actually has changed.  Do a

`md5 /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd` or `cat /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd`

when it works, and after it stops working.  If it changes, you've gotta figure out why (automatic update from a cronjob?  some website/admin tool changing it for you?)

Note that subversion + apache does *not* change this file in any way if you're using any form of default setup.

I also hope that you replace $AUTH_USER with your proper username ;-) (or at least have exported the variable).

If the file hasn't changed, then it's something else.  See if there's anything in the apache error log.

A few other possibilities:

- Try disabling https (for testing - since you probably don't have a valid certificate).
- Check your .subversion/auth folder;  I'm not sure about tortoisesvn, but I believe it stores credential information there (just like vanilla svn).
- Not likely, but instead of recreating your user see if `touch /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd` will do the trick.
- Is the file writable by anyone but root?  If so, `chmod 644 /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd`

Answer (score -1):

I'm using TortoiseSVN as well, but on Windows users' passwords are managed by [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) on the network domain. So usernames are in the format `<domain>\<user>`. And from time to time (weeks), I need to reset the password; it seems like the password is changed. I just do not know why.